# Optimal number of files per directory vs number of directories for EXT4

Tags: linux, ext4

I have a program that produces large number of small files (say, 10,000 files). After they are created, another script accesses them and processes one by one.

Questions:

- does it matter, in terms of performance, how the files are organized (all in one directory or in multiple directories)
- if so, then what is the optimal number of directories and files per dir?

I run Debian with *ext4* file system

**Related**

- [Maximum number of files/folders on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238860/maximum-number-of-files-folders-on-linux)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/104986/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-files-a-file-system-can-contain

Comment: What do you mean by *large number* ?  10^3 ? 10^6 ? 10^9 ?  Do you want the files to remain on disk after the script has read them or can you delete them ?

Comment: Good question, IMO; could be construed as subjective with no single definitive answer (a bit vague, considering hardware variance etc.) but I think that's being a bit intolerant to answering the problem, to which there will be valuable answers (and the experts will have an idea of the thresholds to work with to crunch numbers).

Comment: `10k`, as is the question. Why does it matter if I delete them later?

Comment: As pointed out in the answers to this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238860/maximum-number-of-files-folders-on-linux -- a directory containing a large number of files can be something of a challenge to many utilities such as `ls` and `rm. This can be ignored if you delete the files as soon as you are done with them.

Comment: Do you only want answers for your case (10k files, which is actually not very large these days for modern UNIX filesystems) or do you want general answers about a 'large number'? Do you want to know the asymptotic big-O behavior as N passes 10^6, 10^9 ... (I came here hoping to find that).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

10k files inside a single folder is not a problem on Ext4. It should have the `dir_index` option enabled by default, which indexes directories content using a btree-like structure to prevent performance issues.

To sum up, unless you create millions of files or use ext2/ext3, you shouldn't have to worry about system or FS performance issues.

That being said, shell tools and commands don't like to be called with a lot of files as parameter ( `rm *` for example) and may return you an error message saying something like 'too many arguments'. Look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657488/what-happens-if-there-are-too-many-files-under-a-single-directory-in-linux) for what happens then.

Comment: what if there are some 40 million small files in a directory what problems it can cause?

Comment: @stackit you can break the directory index and Linux will automatically make the filesystem read-only. See https://adammonsen.com/post/1555/ and https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29894